# Best way of calling a function with different arguments passed by reference when you only need one of these arguments

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference

this is a simple question:

If I have to call a method like this, for instance:

```
void getBounds(float &xmin, float &ymin, float &zmin,
             float &xmax, float &ymax, float &zmax)
```

What is the proper way to call the method, if I just need the information stored in xmax? I don't want to create variables that I'm not going to use.

Is there a way to do this? Let's say that the incorrect way of doing what I want would be something like:

```
float xmax;
getBounds(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, xmax, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Now I'm using dummy-trash variables, but maybe there is another way.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I cannot edit the method, is from a third-party library.

Comment: I don't think you can set nullptr if you are taking references

Comment: `std::optional` can be a direct solution to your question. However, I don't understand the real need behind this. You may have a design issue. In this case, why don't you implement a `getXMax` function ?

Comment: Assuming you can't change the signature of the call, you could create one dummy variable: `float dummy; float xmin; getBounds(xmin, dummy, dummy, dummy, dummy, dummy);` Which however might still not be safe, since the function might use the values of these references internally to determine for example xmin.
With no further information on the contract `getBounds` provides, you probably need to create five dummy variables and pass them. (However you could hide that in a nice little wrapper function.)

Comment: Your title is incorrect: the arguments are not passed by value, they are passed by reference (to be written). I suggested an edit.

Comment: i think you may want to send `0` instead of nulls

Comment: I'm not sure the implementation details of a function should affect the way it is called.  I suggest encapsulation; put the function and the data together, on an object.

Comment: I forgot to mention I cannot edit the method.

I am doing the "dummy" thing, I was asking if there is another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you modify `getBounds` or not?  If you can, and calculating
each of the values is expensive, it *might* be worth changing it
to pass pointers, and only do the relevant calculation if the
pointer is non-null.  Otherwise, you'll need to pass an lvalue
(variable) to each.  And theoretically, if you pass the same
variable to more than one argument, you could get undefined
behavior in the function (say because the function starts with
something along the lines of `xmin = ymin = 0.0;`).

Finally, unless the calculation of each value is expensive, and the
function skips it if it gets a null pointer, creating and
passing the extra variables is unlikely to have any impact on
performance.

Comment: I cannot modify getBounds, this would be the best solution, of course. I can create a wrapper and mask the method, though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
float dummy;
float xmax;

getBounds(dummy, dummy, dummy, xmax, dummy, dummy);
```

This will only create one variable on the stack, thus saving space - creating more of them won't have any side-effect other than taking up another 4 bytes each [assuming "nornal" sized floats, standard does not specify exact size of float] - it takes the same amount of time to create one or five (or a hundred) stack based, uninitialized variables.

Using pointers would allow you to pass in a `nullptr`, however, that will also add an extra check in the `getBounds`, so

```
void getBounds(....)
{
    xmin = the_getXmin_function();
    ...
}
```

becomes:

```
void getBounds(....)
{
    if (xmin != nullptr)
        *xmin = the_getXmin_function();
    ...
}
```

assuming `the_getXmin_function` is trivial, this will slow the code down. If the function is complex, then having an if, and "I don't want this" option would help performance quite a bit.

Comment: Mats Peterrsson; this could be unsafe: you don't know how getBounds is consuming the variables: they may be used in intermediate steps. Yes you could read the source code, but that source code could change in future versions.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. That it would be a pretty bad implementation of the function if it uses input reference parameters for internal calculations - if nothing else because it's slower.

Comment: In this case, why do not directly expose `the_getXmin_function()` and alike functions to the world ?

Comment: Bad implementation: yes I agree. But if you've ever worked with, say windows API, then you get to know about bad implementation!

Comment: @MatsPetersson The question is whether the arguments are out or in-out (since they are non-const references, we can assume that they are not in).  But even if they are purely out, if `getBounds` does something like `xmax = (xmin = something) + 1`, and `xmax` and `xmin` refer to the same object, you have undefined behavior.  (Personally, I would argue that you should be able to pass the same variable unless documented otherwise.  Practically, I suspect that the reverse corresponds closer to the reality.)

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledge to Mats Petersson: you can't pass nullptr as the function requires references.

If the function has no warranty attached to it, then you should create temporary variables and pass them all in. It would be unsafe to pass the same variable; in case it's used in internal computation.

Even if the function works with the same variable passed, there is no guarantee that someone won't change the implementation of that function in a way that causes your code to break. You could be opening yourself up to nasty bugs in the future.

Comment: Technically, you CAN NOT pass a `nullptr` as to something that takes a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send nullptr if the function is waiting for a reference

But if you change your function signature for a pointer the you can go for something like: `void getBounds(float *xmax, float *xmin = nullptr, float *ymin = nullptr, float *zmin = nullptr, float *ymax = nullptr, float *zmax = nullptr) { }`

and call it: `getBounds( &xmax);` but then you must check in your function if the variable is nullptr or no

but as said in the comment it will only work in one case

Comment: Your  solution works only for `xmax`. And putting `xmax` before `xmin` while `ymin` is before `ymax` is really a bad idea.

Comment: I cannot change the function. I put the nullptr example to show you what I want, I know it's totally incorrect ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote that method, just change the function's signature to

```
void getBounds( float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, float* )
```

so that you can pass `nullptrs` if you want to ignore a parameter. Otherwise you might want to write a wrapper function.

```
void getBounds( float*a, float*b, float*c, float*d, float*e, float*f )
{
    float dummy;
    getBounds( 
        a ? *a : dummy, 
        b ? *b : dummy, 
        c ? *c : dummy, 
        d ? *d : dummy, 
        e ? *e : dummy, 
        f ? *f : dummy );
}
```

If your situation doesn't occur regularly then another way of handling this could be to write

```
float xmax; // in outer scope
{
    float dummy; // in inner scope. Will be thrown away afterwards
    getBounds( dummy, dummy, dummy, xmax, dummy, dummy );
}
```

so you don't litter your scope.

I would prefer the first variant.

Comment: Well, since my edit suggestion was rejected (...) I will comment: your pointer-parameters overload is currently incorrect and won't compile, the six expressions like `a ? *a : &dummy` should be like `a ? *a : dummy` (`&dummy` -> `dummy`). Edit: you just edited yourself :p (You're welcome)

Answer (score 0):

If you can rewrite getBounds and can use C++11 consider using tuple, tie and ignore:

```
std::tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float> getBounds()
{
  std::tuple<float, float, float, float, float, float> r;
  :
  std::get<3>(r) = ...;
  :
  return(r);
}
:
float xmax;
std::tie(std::ignore, std::ignore, std::ignore, xmax, std::ignore, std::ignore> = getBounds();
```

--EDIT--

As you cannot change it you may overload it. Parameterless version would just wrap around the original one, pack everything in a tuple and return it.